# Conditions for number of solutions for a given system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

I need to find the conditions for $a$ and $b$ such that
$$3x-2y+z=b$$
$$5x-8y+9z=3$$
$$2x+y+az=-1$$
has (i) unique solution, (ii) no solution (iii) infinitely many solutions

Here's what I did. Firstly, I put the situation into an augmented matrix form, and tried reducing to row echelon form to get the rank. Let C be the augmented matrix $C=[A:B]$ for the system of equations $AX=B$

$$ C= \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  3&-2&1&b\\
  5&-8&9&3\\
  2&1& a & -1\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

The operations that I used, in order, are:

$$R_1 \rightarrow R_1-R_2$$

$$R_1\rightarrow \frac{-R1}{2}$$

$$R_2\rightarrow R_2-5R_1$$

$$R_3\rightarrow R_3-2R_1$$

$$R_3 \rightarrow R_3-R_2$$
Reducing using these operations to row echelon form, I got:

$$ C= \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&-3&4&\frac{3-b}{2}\\
  0&7&-11&3+5(\frac{3-b}{2})\\
  0&0& a+3 & \frac{7b-29}{2}\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

I know, for unique solution, the ranks of A and C must be equal, and they should be equal to 3 (the number of unknowns), i.e.,
$$\rho(A)=\rho(C)=3$$

$($rank of the matrix A is being denoted by $\rho(A)$$)$

$\implies a+3\neq0$ and, $b \in \mathbb{R}$

This is the correct answer.

However, for no solution, I know that $\rho(A)\neq\rho(C)$

That is possible when, $a+3=0$ and $\frac{7b-29}{2} \neq 0$ $\implies b \neq \frac{29}{7}$

But, the answer says the conditions are $a = -3 $ and $b \neq \frac{1}{3}$ for the no solution part. What is my mistake here? I don't know where I went wrong, any help would be nice. If someone can point out the error in my steps, it would be very helpful

Comment: Is it not $27b-9$ instead of $7b-29$?

Comment: According to the transformations that I used, no, that isn't the case. I'll edit the post with the transformations I used

Comment: Your solution seems correct, but I didn't check your work in reducing the matrix, and I believe this is probably where the mistake is. This is what I would check.

Comment: I obtain for $a=-3$ that  $b=1/3$ and $x=(5(3z - 1))/21$ , $y=(11(3z - 1))/21$.

Comment: As can be checked using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref+%7B%7B3%2C-2%2C1%2Cb%7D%2C%7B5%2C-8%2C9%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2Ca%2C-1%7D%7D), you must have made a mistake in your row operations.

Comment: Could you take a look whether the operations that I have used are valid or not?

Comment: They are not valid (start computing it again independently).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Are you saying that the operations that I used are incorrect, or that the operations are correct but I made a mistake while calculating?

Comment: A mistake while calculating.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Alright, I'll try them again independently now

Comment: @DietrichBurde Found the mistake, but also thanks for helping me verify that my method is correct, as I had a doubt in these kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed to be a calculation error. I have now found that the previous row-echelon form that I got was incorrect